# Discord bot embed msg error Must be 2048 or fewer in length

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js, bots, embed

I am getting an error when I run the code which is for an embed message's description in discord bot.

*"embed.description: Must be 2048 or fewer in length."*

The content is taken from an API and it can be more than 6000. How can I make 2 or 3 embed message with different description depending on the data taken from API?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While the `channel#send()` method accepts an [options object](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/typedef/MessageOptions) where you can set the `split` property to `true` to split the content into multiple messages if it exceeds the character limit, `setDescription` doesn't have it.

It means, you need to create these "chunks" and send them one by one if you want to have it in the embed's description.

You can either create your own method or... Discord has a helper method named [`splitMessage()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Util?scrollTo=s-splitMessage) inside [`Util`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Util) that you can use to split a string into multiple chunks at a designated character that do not exceed a specific length. The character it splits by is `\n` by default. If your huge text doesn't have any newline characters, you will need to update the [SplitOptions](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/typedef/SplitOptions) and change the `char` to a single space (i.e. `splitMessage(text, { char: ' ' })`).

To create the chunks, you can use the following:

```js
const chunks = Discord.Util.splitMessage(prettyLongText);
```

It returns an array, so you can iterate over the results. Check out the working code below:

```js
const chunks = Discord.Util.splitMessage(texts[args[0]]);
const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed().setTitle(`Split me!`);

if (chunks.length > 1) {
  chunks.forEach((chunk, i) =>
    message.channel.send(
      embed
        .setDescription(chunk)
        .setFooter(`Part ${i + 1} / ${chunks.length}`),
    ),
  );
} else {
  message.channel.send(embed.setDescription(chunks[0]));
}
```

[image]

If you're using a simple embed object, you need to update like this:

```js
const chunks = Discord.Util.splitMessage(texts[args[0]]);

if (chunks.length > 1) {
  chunks.forEach((chunk, i) =>
    message.channel.send(
      {
        embed: {
          color: 3447003,
          description: chunk,
          footer: {
            text: `Part ${i + 1} / ${chunks.length}`,
          },
          title: 'Split me!',
        },
      }
    ),
  );
} else {
  message.channel.send({
    embed: {
      color: 3447003,
      description: chunks[0],
      title: 'Split me!',
    },
  });
}
```

Comment: In my case the embed is different

`embed: {
                  Title: "Session Details",
                  color: 3447003,
                  description: `${msg1}`, `

So how can i set foofter here, I used this
 ` setFooter: `Part ${i + 1} / ${s_str.length}` `

But Nothing comes

Comment: You need to add a `footer` object that has a `text` property. I've just updated my answer above, please check it.